# Add headers to every response

Tags: symfony, silex

How can I "automatically" add a header to every response with Silex?

So far I have to do following with every response:

```php
$app->post('/photos'), function () use ($app) {
    return $app->json(array('status' => 'success'), 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'));
});
```

Instead, I would like to use a before filter to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` automatically with every request:

```php
// Before
$app->before(function () use ($app) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});

// Route
$app->post('/photos'), function () use ($app) {
    return $app->json(array('status' => 'success')); // <-- Not working, because headers aren't added yet.
});
```

Comment: Why don't you overload the Response class ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `after` application middleware, this is the method signature:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // ...
});
```

This way you get the Response object that you can freely modify.

Comment: I also needed to output a header for every request but just added it to my index.php, is the above method the better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you added a simple `header()` call? You should do it in the `after()` handler like in my answer.

Comment: Does this need to be at a certain place in the code? It is breaking my app for some reason.

Comment: AFAIK you can define an after middleware anywhere.

Comment: Simple `header` calls didn't work that great. Better to do something like this in the `after` block `$response->headers->set('key', 'value');`